# HAML link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I made this HAML link:

```
= link_to "Create Profile", signup_path
```

I was thinking it should work since this url works:

```
http://m.cmply.local:8800/signup
```

But instead I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<#<Class:0x129a08190>:0x129a027e0>
```

Here is my routes.rb snippet

```
  scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
               { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout",
                 :sign_up => "signup" },
                 :controllers => {:sessions => "mobile/sessions"}

      resources :home

      resources :disclosures # Will have new, get, look up a disclosure

    end
  end
```

and here is the rake routes snippet

```
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"}
 new_user_registration GET    /signup(.:format)
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your routes.rb and your `rake routes` output

Comment: @DanS just posted the routes.rb snippet, now getting the rake result

Comment: @Dans also just posted the snippet with the right rake route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `signup_path` to `new_user_registration_path`

Comment: that gave this error: Illegal element: classes and ids must have values. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because rails does not know what "signup_path" is. I would recommend you run `bundle exec rake routes` and *be sure* that `signup_path` is actually in those routes. I can tell by looking at your `routes.rb` file that you're not going to have the `signup_path` route.

The route you are looking for is going to be something more like `users_signup_path`, because devise likes to wrap its routes in namespaces like that.

Comment: here is the output for my rake routes for this route: {:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"} new_user_registration GET    /signup(.:format)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing app_main.signup_path. It seems that is getting called on a different engine.
I've ran into this problem before.

And follow the directions of others such as to check your routes.